# Make NSTableCellText update while entering NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a 1 column `NSTableView` hooked up to an array controller. I also have an `NSTextField` setup to the same array controller.

I got everything working fine. When I change a selection in the `NSTableView`, the `NSTextField` is also updated. When I update the `NSTextField` and hit enter, the `NSTableView` displays the changes.

What I want is the `NSTableView` cell to update (character for character) while I update the `NSTextField` and not have to wait until enter until I see the changes in the cell.

How do I do this?

For an example, look at how this is done in the Note application on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the delegate method

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
```

This will be called by the NSTextField delegate each time the text changes. Therefore you could update your object within this method and it will be reflected in your tableview.